# Why are my bootstrap cards overlapping on small devices?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

The following code uses 3 bootstrap cards that display perfectly side by side on large screens. However, on medium size screens, the cards start to overlap and on the small ones, they completely overlap.
I tried to play with `class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2"` and changed the md-4s to 3s and the sm-2s to 3s and 4s to see if anything would change, but it didn't.

After resizing the window and inspecting the elements containing the `class="card center` classes, I realized that their actual sizes are not reduced on small devices, they're just overlapping on each other.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

```css
body {
  /* border: solid 2px red; */
  background-color: #EDEFEE;
  font-family: 'Markazi Text', serif;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 912px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*="col-"] {
    width: 33%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .container {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
        <div class="card center" style="width: 18rem; height: 90%;">
          <img src="assets/img/ragout.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="height: 245px;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title bg-warning text-danger">Ragout de pomme de terre<span class="badge bg-primary">New</span></h2>
            <p class="card-text">Potato cooked with beef and carrot.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
        <div class="card center" style="width: 18rem; height: 90%;">
          <img src="assets/img/table.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="height: 245px;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">Book a table</h2>
            <p class="card-text">Potato cooked with beef and carrot.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
        <div class="card center" style="width: 18rem; height: 90%;">
          <img src="assets/img/open.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="height: 245px;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">Open hours</h2>
            <p class="card-text">Potato cooked with beef and carrot.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you explicitly setting your card widths (`18rem`)?

Comment: @Pieterjan If I don't set it, the cards will be very long. They will stretch in height and won't look nice at all.

Comment: You're fighting against the library here with some of your styles. It's a bad idea to override column widths. Use the grid as designed or use Bootstrap's [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/) feature. You'll make life much harder down the road with such heavy-handed styling. Also, your `img~p` selector doesn't seem to match anything, but you almost certainly shouldn't be using absolute positioning like that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want three columns, use column size `4` (12/3). Review the [grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#how-it-works) to see that column classes should be mobile (smallest) first, if only for convention and readability, and you don't need to repeat breakpoints with the same quantity. For example, `col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2` should just be `col-sm-2 col-md-4`.

Then, don't use inline styles. They cause much repetition and make your code much harder to maintain. Use custom styles *where Bootstrap doesn't already offer classes*, such as the [padding classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding) I'm using on the container element.

Finally, margin on the body element doesn't really work as the body is generally the size of the viewport, so margin would be *outside* the viewport. Use padding on the body or margin on inner elements.

```css
body {
  background-color: #EDEFEE;
  font-family: 'Markazi Text', serif;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<main>
  <div class="container pt-3 pt-md-0">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="card center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title bg-warning text-danger">Ragout de pomme de terre<span class="badge bg-primary">New</span></h2>
            <p class="card-text">Potato cooked with beef and carrot.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="card center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">Book a table</h2>
            <p class="card-text">Potato cooked with beef and carrot.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="card center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">Open hours</h2>
            <p class="card-text">Potato cooked with beef and carrot.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are using `"col-sm-2"` for the cards which mean it will show 1/6 which indicates it will show 6 cards on small screen? is that what you want?
make the class like that `class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-10"` or `class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6"` if you want to show two or one card in small screens then you can adjust it accordingly